# About Euclid's proof of infinite primes.....

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was checking that if product of first n primes+1 gives a prime again is true to how many n

For example $$2+1=3$$ is a prime$$2\times 3+1=7$$ is a prime$$2\times 3\times 5+1=31$$ is a prime$$2\times 3\times 5\times 7+1=211 $$ is a prime$$2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11+1=2311$$ is a prime $$2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11\times 13+1=30031$$ is composite

So prime chain is broken and further steps will give composite no.s only

Now as I understood from proof of infinite primes Euclid said multiply all primes and add 1 and you will get another prime. It proves that there are infinite primes

Then my question is how can we guarantee that the resulting number is prime??

Or it should be that we will get another prime dividing the resulting number

Please help me to clear my confusion!!!!

Comment: It was Euclid, not Euler (Euler proved that there are infinitely many primes in different ways). The argument of Euclid is not that $Q_n := p_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot p_n + 1$ is a prime, but that it has a prime factor, call it $q$. And $q$ cannot be one of the $p_i$. Hence no finite set of primes is the set of all primes.

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_theorem

It does not say that "if you multiply all primes and add 1 and you will get another prime".

Comment: @RobertZ But it can be expressed in that form when it is a proof *by contradiction*. But in that case it doesn't imply anything about the *actual* integers (only about the *hypothetical* integers having a finite number of primes). This is one of the most common confusions about proofs by contradiction (and it widespread for this particular proof).

Comment: @BillDubuque Are you sure? Suppose there are finitely many primes. Let $n$ be their product plus one. $n$ cannot be divisible by any prime. Therefore... $n$ is a new prime? That doesn't follow.

Comment: @JackM, I agree with you, for example, 2.3.5.7.9.11.13=59.509 which makes it composite. the correct statement is that P+1 will contain a prime number which is not among those which are multiplied.

Comment: @Jack Yes, I am sure. The (common) path to contradiction mentioned in my prior comment uses the theorem that an integer $>1$ having no smaller prime factor is prime. Thus since $\,n = p_1\cdots p_k+1\,$ has no smaller prime factor, it is prime, but not one of the $\,p_i,\,$ contradiction. It's essential to keep in mind that reasoning in contradictory theories can appear very strange, e.g. we can alternatively finish as follows: $\,n\,$ has no prime factors so $\,n = 1\,$ so $\, p_1\cdots p_k = 0\,$ so there are no primes. There are *many* ways to reach contradictions in contradictory theories.

Comment: @AtulMishra It is not necessarily true that, "...further steps will give composite numbers only." The product of the first $11$ primes $+1$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Wikipedia**:

Consider any finite list of prime numbers $p_1, p_2,\cdots , p_n.$ It will be shown that at least one additional prime number not in this list exists. Let $P$ be the product of all the prime numbers in the list: $P = p_1p_2...p_n$. Let $q = P + 1$. Then let us check if $q$ is prime or not:

$(1)$: If $q$ is prime, then there is at least one more prime than is in the list.

$(2)$: If $q$ is not prime, then some prime factor $p$ divides $q$. If this factor $p$ were on our list, then it would divide $P$ (since $P$ is the product of every number on the list); but $p$ divides $P + 1 = q$. If $p$ divides $P$ and $q$, then $p$ would have to divide the difference of the two numbers, which is $(P + 1) − P = 1$. Since no prime number divides $1, p$ cannot be on the list. This means that at least one more prime number exists beyond those in the list.

---

This proves that for every finite list of prime numbers there is a prime number not on the list, and therefore there must be infinitely many prime numbers.

Comment: Yes I didn't read about the second case and confusion occurred

Comment: I hope you understood fully now.

Answer (score 3):

The proof relies on the fact that every prime is in that product, and that a prime can't divide both a number and that number plus one.

Assume there are finitely many primes.  If $c$ is their product, then $p$ divides $c$ for any prime $p$.  Therefore $p$ does not divide $c+1$ for any prime $p$.  This is a contradiction, every integer has a prime divisor (for primes, this divisor is itself).

Note that $30031 = 59 \times 509$. Neither $59$ nor $509$ were included in your product and so there is no contradiction. The proof doesn't claim that this product of primes plus one construction always yields a prime.

Comment: Or we can conclude: $c$ is not divisible by any *smaller* prime, hence $c$ is prime, contra the list includes all primes. *That* is the form of the proof by contradiction that often misleads beginners to conclude that the Euclidean construction always produces primes.

Answer (score 1):

Euclid's proof of infinite primes is not to give a method of generating infinite primes, it is to prove that there are cannot be a **finite** set of primes, which are two very different things.

It is non-constructive and the entire basis of the proof is to show that assuming a finite set of primes will lead to a contradiction by definition since $a \times b \times c \times d \ \times .... + 1$ cannot be divisible by any of the product terms if $a, b, c, ... \in \mathbb{N}$ as this would say that $\frac{1}{a}$ is an integer.

Comment: No, Euclid's proof is constructive (not by contradiction) and it does give an algorithm to generate an infinite list of primes. It shows how given any finite set of prime one can construct a new prime not in that set.

Comment: :-P If $p=a\times b\times c\times\dots+1$, then either $p$ is a prime number (boom!  New prime!) or it factors into more primes that were not the original ones (boom!  Even more primes!), so it does generate primes, though not in any efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Euler nor Euclid said any such thing. Euclid wrote that if $p_1,..,p_n$ are primes and $q$ is $1$ more than their product , then any prime divisor of $q$ is  a prime not equal to any of $p_1,...,p_n.$

If   $p$ is the least $m>1$ that divides $q$ then $p$ is a prime divisor of $k.$ So $q$ does indeed have a prime divisor.